# dns in Dockercontainer not working with vue.js and node: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db

Tags: node.js, vue.js, docker-compose

I created a vue.js app which I know try to dockerize.
As Backend I'm using node.js for api calls, which is using mysql as a database. 
So I try to create an ui container, a db container, and also a container for nginx.

When trying to create these via `docker-compose up --build`, I get the following error.

Does anybody know what is the problem here?

```
$ vue-cli-service build

-  Building for production...
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    [...]
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'db',
  fatal: true
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
ERROR: Service 'ui' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c yarn run build' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

This is my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

networks:
  app-tier:

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always
    networks:
      - app-tier
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      [...]
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  ui:
    build: ./ui
    container_name: ui
    restart: always
    networks:
      - app-tier
    expose:
      - 80
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

  [...]
```

This **.ui/Dockerfile**

```
# build stage
FROM node:12.14.0-alpine as build-stage
[...]
# RUN yarn server
RUN yarn run build

# Production stage
FROM nginx:1.16.1-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
[...]
```

This is **./ui/src/server/db.js:**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'db',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'dbname',
    port: '3306'
});
connection.connect();
module.exports = connection;
```

Comment: not sure, but i think you need first to install dependencies before build in your *.ui/Dockerfile*. And can be *mysql* lib used in the browser? Or where is `db.js` running?

Comment: Probably your `host: 'db'` should be the reason for the error, try to change the value to `localhost`

Comment: db.js is running in in the node.js server. and "db" is the name of the mysql container.

Comment: what happens if you build your app without docker? The error says clearly that `db` can not be found. `host` must be a valid hostname like `localhost` or `example.org`

Comment: If I wouldn't use docker I would use localhost, but this case node.js is running in docker container "ui" and mysql is running in "db"

Comment: so you are mixing your server with a Vue app. This is very bad idea. Ideally your Frontend and your node server are different services with different images running in different containers. This is why you become the error if building the Vue app. Second: `db` is just a container name and has nothing to do with the hostname